# How to implement "Hot Keys" using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, key

I know this question has been asked before. I read them but all of them suggest different things.Below is my question:

I have a form in html and php. When I click the button of my form, I insert the form data to database using ajax call. But now I want to add shortcut. That is I want to provide additional controlling. If user presses "CTRL" and "s" , I want the data to be inserted into the database.

Is it possible to do with jquery (I am using ajax to insert data). If anyone knows how to do that please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 83 && e.ctrlKey) {
            alert('ctrl s');
        }
    });
```

Comment: nice!! 
thnx, was looking for this :)